# Is it possible to make IntelliJ recognize and display tooltips for Istio objects?

Tags: intellij-idea, kubernetes, istio

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 doesn't recognize Istio objects (CRDs). Is it possible to make IntelliJ recognize and display tooltips for Istio objects? I searched for plugins - there isn't a istio plugin. I do have Kubernetes plugin installed.

[image: s it p]

[image]

Comment: Not at the moment. Planned to add this in scope of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes [Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10485-kubernetes) does not support custom resources defined by Istio project, feature [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197971) has been submitted. Thanks @Andrey for his effort. Answer has been provided for any further contributors research.

Answer (score 16):

The Kubernetes plugin now supports custom resource. You can add a custom resource for Istio by URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/api/master/kubernetes/customresourcedefinitions.gen.yaml in "Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Kubernetes".